# Save to django imagefield

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to

1) Take an uploaded image and change it black and white with pillow

2) In the view save the original file to a FileField called "file"

3) In the view save the black and white version to ImageField called "thumbnail_225"

1 and 2 is working great but I cannot seem to figure out #3.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

**View**

```
def archive_media_upload(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            m = form.save(commit=False)

            m.user = request.user
            m.type = 1

                        # create black and white
            image = Image.open(m.file)
            black_and_white = image.convert("L")

                        #HOW DO I SAVE/ASSIGN BW IMAGE TO the "thumbnail_225" ImageField?

            m.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('archive_media_archive'))

    else:
        form = UploadForm(initial={'user': request.user })

    return render(request, 'archive_app/archive_media_upload.html', {'archive':True, 'show_upgrade_link': show_upgrade_link,'form': form})
```

**Model**

```
class Media(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    type = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)

    thumbnail_225 = models.ImageField(upload_to="thumbnail_images/", blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep it short, what you are looking for is (I think) is the `clean` method. You should defined it in your form:

class UploadForm(forms.Form):

```
thumbnail_225  = forms.ImageField()

...

def clean_thumbnail_225 (self):
    thumbnail_225 = self.cleaned_data["thumbnail_225"]
    image = Image.open()
    black_and_white = image.convert("thumbnail_225")
    ...
    # return the clean data...
```

Note the above code is only a general scheme. It won't really work and does not contain all the correct logic and\or syntax. It was meant only for demonstration. The full hints are found in [DJANGO's form and field validation documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/)